# How to pick one object out of duplicates in an array in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

So i have an example array here. [image: Data from database]

What i need is to create a new array where it only contains one of each name. Example 1 nucycle object and 1 beby object only but both objects must have customer_id=1. The category and the rest dont matter.  I have tried a for loop where i compare with the previous object name where if it matches then it will be ignored. But that doesnt work if the arrangement is more randomized. I can also use a counter where it stops pushing after 2 push in but that's fixed and static as i dont know in the future how many names there will be. Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

You could use a map to achieve this
See the snippet below

```js
function removeDuplicate(arrayOfObject){
  let store = new Map()
  
  return arrayOfObject.filter(obj=>{
  // If the item exist in the store already return false and do not add it to the new array
    if(store.get(obj.name) === obj.customer_id ){
      return false
    }  
    // If other wise, add it and return true
    store.set(obj.name, obj.customer_id)
    return true
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for unique set of objects based on `name` keys:

```
const distinctItems = [...new Map(array.map(item => [item["name"], item])).values()];
```